# Привести регулярное выражение для поиска строки вида 8 (912) любое количество символов 12

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Когда использую такое выражение `[8]{1}[\s]{1}[(]{1}[9]{1}[12]+[)]{1}`, то выражение может находить в том числи такие варианты 8 (9121) или 8 (912121), то есть нужно 12 один и более раз, а рассматривает 1 как отдельное число, что не соответствует условию.

Comment: Приведите примеры текстов и что в них найти в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Comment: Дело в том, что в вопросе и есть полное описание ТЗ. Могу предположить, что число 12 по такому условию может встречаться и вне пределов круглых скобок, но ответ принял, поскольку более вероятно, что именно Ваше регулярное выражение хотят видеть в этом вопросе.

Comment: вопрос не понятен. Лучше его переформулировать и/или привести примеры. В частности, непонятно, какому условию не соответствует, почему текущее вырежение не подходит и что вообще нужно найти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
8\s\(9(12)+\)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5css1

```
8 (912)
8 (91212)
8 (9121)
8 (912121)
```